# Client Time shown instead of server Time in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am into strange issue of javascript `Date()` function, these are the details

> Server Side : Struts (ActionForm, Action class, jsp)
>   Client Side : jQuery, javascript

Now, I need a server time on the page and manipulate using javascript. So, I did  `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeinMillis();` in the action class and save it as an ActionForm attribute.

Now, at the client side, I got the long value (timeinMillis) from the styleId. But, to manipulate, when I do

```
var curTime = parseInt($("#serverTime").val());
var serverTime = new Date(curTime);
```

Now, the serverTime is providing client machine date and not server date though we are providing timeinMillis of server.

The strange part is when I pass string value of a date instead of long timeinMillis from server and pass it as an argument, it works well.

Any idea?

Comment: Hmm.... by how much do your server and client time differ - is that a timezone difference?

Comment: @davida. yes it is a timezone difference. say the server is running in london and person is accessing from US, and what we want is that the person who is sitting in london will see the server timing of US and local timing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue with help of the above hints.

From java side, taken the offset from the UTC with the day light saving option.

so, in Action class

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone z = c.getTimeZone();
int offset = z.getOffset(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

This gives the offset of local timezone and UTC timezone including day light saving

At the javascript, I used,

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
var sd = new Date(now_utc.getTime() + offset);
alert("The Server time is " + sd.toLocaleString());
```

And, this gives correct server time with the day light saving options.

Thanks a lot for your help, without them, would not be possible to work it out. Cheers!

Comment: What if the client and the server WON'T be synced (e.g. someone has time off by 5 minutes on their's laptop)? I'd consider sending both server timestamp and it's timezone offset, or some (standardized) textual representation of date - if I had to implement this, I'd probably stick with the latter.

Comment: you are very correct david, I agree with you and was thinking about the same, but then need to stick to something, have a look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134925/user-reputation-graph-uses-client-date

Answer (score 5):

This is because your javascript runs on client machine, so when you create new Date() in javascript it picks up the client machine time.

Answer to second query if you pass the sever date as string it will create date object of that date.

Use below function

```
    function calcTime(offset) {
        // create Date object for current location
        d = new Date();
       // convert to msec, add local time zone offsetand  get UTC time in msec
        utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

        // create new Date object with supplied offset
        nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

        // return time as a string
        return "The Server time is " + nd.toLocaleString();

    }
```

Here you need to pass the offset of your server time with UTC

Comment: Hi, you answer was helpful, but still did not get the exact timing. However, I resolved the issue, look at my version of answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution in PHP:

```
  var phpDate = '<?php echo date('Y/m/d H:m:s');?>'
    , serverDate = new Date(phpDate)
    , month = serverDate.getMonth()+1 //getMonth() returns a 0-based number.
    , day = serverDate.getDate()
    , year = serverDate.getFullYear();

  console.log(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
```

Comment: You should read with more attention and understand the response context. The answer is right and although it has not been useful to you, it may be for others.

Answer (score 1):

If your server and client time are in different timezones and you want to show this difference to the user, then you have to send timezone information to the client as well.

`Calendar.getInstance().getTimeinMillis()` returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch,  but it does not say anything about the timezone. It's just a number of milliseconds since midnight 1970/1/1 **UTC** and at any instant in time, this number is the same on any system (well, given the time is synced), regardless of system's timezone. This might give you the impression that you were getting client time instead of servers.

The reason why this works with string representation of date is the timezone information included in it, and Javascript's ability to parse that and take it into account when constructing the `Date` object.

Comment: you are correct david, but i wanted a solution, but your answer helped me to get it, please look at my version of answer.